# How can The Voice have live voting during the quarantine?

Tags: game-show, the-voice-us

On Monday night, The Voice was aired with a studio audience, which makes me think it was taped before the quarantine.  But then at the end of the episode, they had a segment where viewers could vote via text, which implied to me that it was live.  How can this be?  Do our votes not actually count?  Or are they somehow exempt from the quarantine?

Comment: https://www.billboard.com/articles/news/9340383/the-voice-episodes-taped-until-end-of-april-john-legend

Comment: What do you mean by "exempt from the quarantine"?

Comment: I'm asking about how it can be a taped show if the TV audience can vote at the end of the show via text.  Either the show is live, and violating quarantine, or it's taped and our votes don't matter.

Comment: & did they air the results segment yet? Does that give anything away. Also, can we get this tagged `the-voice-us` because The Voice is an international franchise - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Voice_(franchise)

Comment: https://ew.com/tv/the-voice-remote-live-shows-coronavirus/